# Temaril-P and agression in dogs

Tags: dogs, training, medicines, aggression

My 5 month old Keeshond puppy is taking [Temaril-P](https://www.drugs.com/vet/temaril-p-tablets.html) and has been exhibiting some aggression (VERY out of character for her).  The vet said she will be back to normal once the steroids are out of her system (early next week), but I'm concerned about a lapse in training.  She's barking and growling at everything, nipping at me, and is very on edge.

Does anyone have any experience using a scenario like this as a training exercise?  It's important to me that no matter what is going on she never bites anyone, ideally I'd like her to be able to self soothe in even the most stressful situations.  Before the steroids she never lost her cool, was extremely tolerant of people (including little kids) and other animals.